# Antd some row properties are not reactive, is it bug or feature, or the code is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to implement the dynamic Row's properties and found justify and align are not updated when the props are updated. Not sure why, maybe something is wrong with the code?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Col, Row, Button, Select } from "antd";
const App = () => {
  const [justify, setjustify] = useState("end");
  return (
    <>
      {justify}
      <Select
        value={justify}
        options={[
          { value: "start", label: "start" },
          { value: "end", label: "end" }
        ]}
        onChange={(val) => {
          setjustify(val);
        }}
      />
      <Row justify={justify} style={{ height: "150px" }} align="bottom">
        <Button type="primary">button1</Button>
        <Button type="primary">button</Button>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

The justify property is changed only on the load, not dynamically. I mean the row is not updated on the property's change.

The code to play with is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-sort-antd-5-0-7-forked-85qlli?file=/demo.js:0-662

Comment: That 's a bug.  You can create a issue in antd github.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique I thought the same, will create an issue. Thanks.